# Differential Equation - Initial Value Problem with Logs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with this exam-style question:[Image of the question and example working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MqZc.jpg)

I am not sure about the reasoning behind why $log(y-1)$ suddenly becomes $log(1-y)$ after multiplying each side by $2$.

Could anyone please clarify why, thanks

Comment: You should note that |y-1| is not necessarily (y-1) and that the mod in the standard formula has some significance. It's not an ornament.

Answer (score 0):

The range of y is given as $[-1,1]$ so that $y-1 \le 0$ .Hence the absolute value $|y-1|=1-y$. Therefore $\log |y-1|=\log (1-y)$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand it now

Comment: @KC1111 Great, you're welcome.